# Express floating point numbers in non standard notation in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to print **1.2e-08** as **12e-09** for display purposes but cannot seem to get the format specifiers.

Is there a way to express floating point numbers in a non standard form without resorting to string operations or using regexes?

Edit: If the question is not clear, I am looking for something that lets me express any number in any scale for example if I want to scale everything in scale of 1e-12 then I should have something like 12000e-12

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the decimal module. It should be able to put it out in the format you want.

http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

For what you are describing (engineering notation), there is a to_eng_string() method.

**EDIT**

In light of your clarification, you can build the number in parts:

```
myNumber = 1.2e-8
myBase = 1e-12
mantissa = myNumber/myBase
print "{0:1}{1:s}".format(mantissa, "{0:1}".format(myBase)[1:])
```

Which would print:
    12000.0e-12

If you knew you would always go to an integer number for the mantissa, you could adjust the format accordingly.

Comment: I already checked that, I know of the decimal module it does not do that for all bases for example if I want to express everything scaled to 1e-12 it wouldnt work.

Comment: I edited to reflect that. I don't think there is a way to do it without string formatting.

Comment: Yea I kinda get that, or you could just split on e and then do the required formatting yourself.

Comment: The format strings I think give the most control over how to print things, they just aren't always clear. This is probably the most concise way to do what you are trying to do. You could just wrap this in a function that returns to you a string given a number and a base. It would be 2 lines (without documentation of course :) )